# .htaccess rewrite specific URL segment to a PHP file and then remove the php file from the URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress site and a custom build app all on the same URL. 
I am looking to redirect all my CMS (custome app) URLs to a certain php controller file. Once redirected I am looking to remove the php file from the URL

e.g. **www.website.com/cms** redirects to **www.website.com/backend.php/cms** but the URL continues to display as **www.website.com/cms**

So far I have the following:

```
# Handle the custom App URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com/cms$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^backend.php/cms/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ backend.php/cms/$1

# Handle the Wordpress URLs by removing index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

EDIT:

The problem is what I have does not work.

If I go to www.website.com/cms I get a 404.

If I go to www.website.com/backend.php/cms the URL does not change to www.website.com/cms, it stays as www.website.com/backend.php/cms

I am not great at .htaccess but think I am going down the correct route.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Updated my question with more info explaining my problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just routing by url:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/cms/(.*)$ /backend.php [L]
#or RewriteRule ^/cms/(.*)$ /yourcms/backend.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

All your magic about 'understanding' the url you do in your cms reading REQUEST_URI.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. My index.php URLs were affected.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this myself by having the following RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^/?cms([A-Za-z0-9\-_\/]+)/?$ /backend.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?cms /backend.php [L]
```

Thanks to those that tried to help :)